# select fieldvalues and column-description of a table

Tags: postgresql

is it possible to retreive the value of a column AND the descirption of each column? I want to see the description behind wach value.

Like:

```
SELECT 
    a.*,
    (SELECT 
        d.description
    FROM
        information_schema.COLUMNS AS c
        LEFT JOIN pg_description as d ON 
        d.objsubid = c.ordinal_position
    WHERE
        TABLE_NAME = <a.tablename> AND column_name = <colname>) as description
FROM table as a
WHERE true;
```

The table should by look like this:

```
id: serial 'no description';
col1: int2 'Column One';
col2: int2 'Column Two';
```

Content:

```
1, 10, 11
2, 20, 21
3, 30, 31
```

The result should look like this:

```
1, 10 (column one), 11 (column two)
2, 20 (column one), 21 (column two)
3, 30 (column one), 31 (column two)
```

Best regards

Christian

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is something like this:

```
select t.id, x.remarks ->> 'id',
       t.col1, x.remarks ->> 'col1',
       t.col2, x.remarks ->> 'col2'
from the_table t
 join lateral ( 
    select jsonb_object_agg(a.attname, col_description(a.attrelid, a.attnum)) as remarks
    from pg_attribute a 
    where a.attrelid = t.tableoid
    and a.attnum > 0
 ) x on true
```

The inner query aggregates all column descriptions of the table into a single JSON value that can be accessed easily in the outer query.